# Переопределение Window.BackgroundProperty.OverrideMetadata

Tags: c#, wpf

пытаюсь переопределить BackgroundProperty у всех Window и его наследований

```
public static void a(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
  //тут точка остановки
}


Window.BackgroundProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Red, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, a));
```

однако в точке останова:

```
e.NewValue = {#FFFFFFFF}
e.OldValue = {#FFFF0000}
```

почему WPF возвращает изначально белый цвет в Background окна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придумал!

Смотрите, проблема вот в чём. Белый цвет берётся из стиля окна по умолчанию, который «сильнее» значения по умолчанию `BackgroundProperty`. (Это можно подсмотреть в Snoop'е.) Значит, надо его (стиль) и переопределить. Но при этом новый стиль нужно основывать на старом, т. к. мы не хотим убирать всё остальное.

Итак, решение. Во-первых, кладём новый стиль в ресурсы приложения:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="ModifiedWindowStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Затем, переопределяем стиль по умолчанию:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var windowStyle = Resources["ModifiedWindowStyle"];
        Window.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(Window),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(windowStyle));
    }
}
```

Всё!

---

PS (от автора вопроса): Сделал так

```
Style winDefaultStyle = new Style() { TargetType = typeof(Window) };
winDefaultStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Window.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red));
Window.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(Window),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(winDefaultStyle));
```

---

PS: Можно всё заинлайнить:

```
Window.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(Window),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Style()
    {
        TargetType = typeof(Window),
        Setters = { new Setter(Window.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red) }
    }));
```

Comment: Да ты гений!!!!

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик: Стараюсь :)

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик: Я только не уверен, нужно ли `Inherits`. Убрал на всякий случай. Без него работает.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант это:

1) Сделать стиль в Словаре ресурсов (назовем его к примеру Styles.xaml).

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" x:Key="MyStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

2) Подключить словарь к приложению (в App.xaml прописать):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

3) Во всех окнах в которых необходим данный стиль использовать:

```
Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"
```

Comment: У меня много окон, некоторые из них не подлежат правке, некоторые появятся в процессе разработки. Мне необходимо задать цвет по умолчанию в одном месте. Указывать стиль в каждом окне для меня плохой вариант.

Comment: Просто TargetType не работает для наследования, т.е. если вы определили стиль для окна TargetType="{x:Type Window}" в глобальном словаре то он не применится для наследников. Поэтому если делать это чисто в Xaml то либо через x:Key и везде его указывать либо через BaseOn для каждого типа окна.

Comment: да я в курсе. Вот ищу решение проблемы. Вроде нашёл, но не очень "изящное".

Answer (score 0):

Вышел из положения. Быдлокод, но работает на все окна. Есть ли более "красивые" способы?

```
protected static Brush gray = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0xD4, 0xD0, 0xC8));

public static void a(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
  if (d is Window)
    if (!object.Equals(e.NewValue, gray))
      d.SetValue(e.Property, gray);
}

public static void Main()
{
  Window.BackgroundProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(gray, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, a));

  ...

}
```

Если кто-то предложит более "красивый" код установки фона окон из **одного** места, то укажу его как ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В `app.xaml` можно переопределить цвет так

```
<Application.Resources>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
  <Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
  </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: тогда и контролы типа TextBox тоже "покраснеют". И деревья тоже....

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик _"тогда и контролы типа TextBox тоже "покраснеют""_ -- т.к. TextBox прозрачный. но можно указать Style. добавил в ответ.

Comment: Ошибаетесь. Он не прозрачный. Попробуйте добавить на Window -> TabControl -> TabItem -> TextBlock (или TreeView) они будут белые, хотя TabItem будет серый => TextBlock имеет цвет и он равен SystemColors.WindowBrushKey. Так что менять эту статическую заливку не стоит.

Comment: в Вашем случае придется применять стиль также для всех Control'ов имеющих Background зависимый от WindowBrushKey

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик  _"придется применять стиль также для всех Control'ов имеющих Background зависимый от WindowBrushKey"_ -- как узнать в каких контролах используется WindowBrushKey?

Comment: Вот тут то и проблема. Только методом появление красных телец =) я предложил вариант решения на свою задачу. Он работает. Но код мне не нравится. Как-то топорно.